# Executing Python script through emacs raises OSError: *.txt not found

Tags: python, emacs, ipython, oserror

I'm trying to execute a Python script through emacs (with C-c C-c) in Elpy mode, but the error "OSError: *.txt not found." raises.
When I just type "ipython script.py" into the console, everything works just fine, so it's got to do something with emacs.
Do you guys have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Are you in the same directory in both cases?

Comment: I assumed I am. Both the txt file and the script are in the same directory. I opened the script in emacs in the terminal, when I already was in the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

This answers my question. I had to change "elpy-shell-starting-directory".

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50905/wrong-cwd-in-python-mode